# Accept any type for which there's a suitable method

Tags: java, generics, operator-overloading, type-bounds

I have the class `MyClass`, which uses the same method name for overloading:

```
public class MyClass {
   void add(Integer val) {
      // ...
   }

   void add(Boolean val) {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Now I'd like to expand this class with an additional `add` method which takes a `Collection<..>`. However, the inner type of the Collection must be able to be passed on as a parameter to an already implemented `add`.

```
public class MyClass {
   void add(Integer val) {
      // ...
   }

   void add(Boolean val) {
      // ...
   }

   void add(Collection<Object> value) {
      for (Object v : value) {
         add(v);  // <-- ERROR here
      }
   }
}
```

When running this it fails with `error: no suitable method found for add(Object)`. I **do** understand *why* this does not work. So my question is, how do I specify `Collection<..>` in a way that says:

> "Accept a Collection where its inner type has a suitable `add` method"

Thanks a lot.

**--- EDIT ---**

The only viable solution is found is doing this:

```
   void addIntegers(Collection<Integer> value) {
      for (Integer v : value) {
         add(v);
      }
   }

   void addBooleans(Collection<Boolean> value) {
      for (Boolean v : value) {
         add(v);
      }
   }
```

Comment: In this specific instance I would say you just need a `add(Object o)` method. I mean, you're not calling `v.add(...)`, you're passing `v` as a parameter.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I want to be more precise with the types, such as specifying `Integer` or `Boolean`. Is there no other way than defining `add(Object o)`?

Comment: Depends on what you want that method to do. As it stands it's impossible to answer your question in any other way (besides what I see in the current answer, which you don't seem to like). But, unless you mean *another* `add` method is called  on the parameter *inside* the method, `Object` seems the right thing to pass, since you don't really seem to care what goes inside `add`.

Comment: @FabioLama Can you accept one of the below or explain why those answers don't work?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the generic `T` as below

```
     <T> void add(Collection<T> value) {
        for (T v : value) {
            if(v instanceof Boolean) {
                add((Boolean) v);
            } else if (v instanceof Integer) {
                add((Integer) v);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + v.getClass());  
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not work, results with `error: no suitable method found for add(T)`

Answer (score -1):

One could write something like:

```
void add(Collection<Object> value) {
      for (Object v : value) {
         if(v instanceof Integer){
             add((int)v); 
         }
         else if(v instanceof Boolean){
             add((boolean)v); 
         }
      }
   }
```

but that doesn't look elegant and nice.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of `instanceof`, but I agree that it's not particularly elegant.